# Does minpts=4 is the best setting for any dataset using DBSCAN algorithm for clustering?

Tags: parameters, cluster-analysis, dbscan

The article on DBSCAN "https://www.aaai.org/Papers/KDD/1996/KDD96-037.pdf" explains that the minpts value must be 4 for any datasets on which the DBSCAN is being used for clustering the data points. Does it gives the best results for any Eps value??

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In later work, the authors suggest to use **minPts = 2 * dim** as default.

> J. Sander, M. Ester, H.-P. Kriegel, and X. Xu. 1998.
> **Density-Based Clustering in Spatial Databases:
>  The Algorithm GDBSCAN and its Applications.**
>  Data Mining and Knowledge Discovery 2, 2 (1998), 169–194.
>   http://dx.doi.org/10.1023/A:1009745219419

If you have duplicates, use a larger value:
"*Our experiments indicate that this value works well for databases D where each point occurs only once, i.e., if D is really a set of points.*"

Smaller values are usually more computationally efficient. Thus, keep minPts small but not too small.

*Always* study your result. Never use it without double checking.

Answer (score 2):

There is no such thing as "always best". IIRC the authors suggested to try that value first. It doesn't mean that you shouldn't try other values sometimes. I usually start with minpts=10...

Also, you still need to vary epsilon. It is probably more important to choose epsilon right than minpts. The two parameters are not independent. Increasing minpts may mean you need
to increase epsilon and the other way around.

Answer (score 1):

Typically your minpts value should be >= d + 1, where d is the dimensionality of your datapoint. So generally it is taken as minpts = 2*d as mentioned by Erich Schubert in the first answer.

But there are cases like when you know your dataset contains lots of noise/outliers it is recommended to make the value of minpts large.

Sometimes you might have to consult a domain expert inorder to get the value of minpts.